# I have a median ifs formula but I am getting a error.Any ideas?

Tags: excel-formula

I realized that a median ifs formula does not exist but I was able to find a work around on the internet.

=MEDIAN(IF('Source Data'!O2:O230="M",IF('Source Data'!N2:N230="3",'Source Data'!J2:J230)))

I keep getting a #NUM! error but have no idea why. The Columns have the same formats.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{=MEDIAN(IF('Source Data'!O2:O230="M",IF('Source Data'!N2:N230=3,'Source Data'!J2:J230)))}
```

Note:

1. replace `"3"` with `3` in your formula;
2. confirm the formula by press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** as it is an **array formula**.

Comment: THANK YOU, I was looking at it for hours.